# Wrong type of markers in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a simple plot, containing 4 sets of data, the 4 lists are plotted as below:

```
for x,y in d1:
    p1 = plt.plot(x,y, 'bo')
for x,y in d14:
    p2 = plt.plot(x,y, 'rs')
for x,y in d56:
    p3 = plt.plot(x,y, 'gx')
for x,y in d146:
    p4 = plt.plot(x,y, 'kD')
plt.legend(['1', '14', '56', '146'], loc='upper left',numpoints = 1)
plt.show()
```

Which gives me a plot like this:[image]

As you can see the markers in the legend are wrong, I tried setting the legend with the legend handler:

```
plt.legend([p1, p2, p3, p4], ["1", "14", "56", "146"], loc="upper left")
```

This plots the graph, with no legend, telling me to use the proxy artist instead as my label objects are not supported. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your for-loops, you are overwriting the variables. Note that is also why the legend in code sample only produces blue makers: your first four plotting calls are probaly in the first for-loop.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that you need the loops

Comment: Your second approach doesnt work, because the plot command returns a list of artists and legend requires only the artist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first try fails because you are calling the plot commands multiple times per loop, so the first four plots are blue makers. Your second try fails because `plt.plot` returns a list of artists. You can make your seconded approach work by adding by

```
p1, = plt.plot(x,y, 'kD')
```

or

```
p1 = plt.plot(x,y, 'kD')[0]
```

instead of

```
p1 = plt.plot(x,y, 'kD')
```

Note the `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

I find the way you are plotting individual points to be problematic.  Trying using zip:

```
In [1]: arr = [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8)]
In [2]: zip(*arr)
Out[2]: [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 2, 4, 6, 8)]
```

This way, you can do

```
x, y = zip(*d1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', label='d1')
x, y = zip(*d14)
plt.plot(x, y, 'rs', label='d14')
x, y = zip(*d56)
plt.plot(x, y, 'gx', label='d56')
x, y = zip(*d146)
plt.plot(x, y, 'kD', label='d146')
plt.legend()
```

instead of using `for` loops.

---

Try labelling each plot with the `label` keyword when you call `plt.plot`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [3]: x1 = np.arange(5)
In [4]: y1, y2, y3, y4 = np.arange(5), np.arange(0, 10, 2), np.arange(0, 2.5, 0.5), np.random.rand(5)
In [5]: plt.plot(x1, y1, 'bo', label='1')
In [6]: plt.plot(x1, y2, 'rs', label='2')
In [7]: plt.plot(x1, y3, 'gx', label='3')
In [8]: plt.plot(x1, y4, 'kD', label='4')
In [9]: plt.legend()
Out[9]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x2b5aed0>
In [10]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I did try that but since I'm looping over the values it creates a label for each point, is there a way to specify just one label?

Comment: you need `p1, = plot(...)` to unpack the list

Comment: @tcaswell That's true, although the code never actually used `p1, ...`, so I just removed them.